# Set password in Cognito PreSignUp_SignUp trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am building a passwordless login system. I want to set the users password in the Pre sign-up cognito trigger to a random string. I can not use a random string generated by the browser as that is insecure. Do you know if it's possible to set a users password inside of the Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom auth flow to achieve your goal. Define Auth Challenge, Create Auth Challenge and Verify Auth Challenge Response those are the triggers responsible to complete your job.

Here below link has working tutorial for this

https://itnext.io/passwordless-sms-authentication-backend-9932391c49dc

If you face any issue to understand please discuss. Thank.